# filter: progid:DXImageTransform fails W3C CSS validation

Tags: css, filter, opacity, alpha-transparency, progid

I am using the following three lines in CSS to enable smooth transitions between "slides", but line #1 fails W3C CSS validation.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.alpha(opacity=100);
-moz-opacity: 1;
opacity: 1;
```

Is there a way to reformulate the same intent (smooth transitions through alpha blending) but with methods that won't fail validation?

Answer (score 3):

You can use IE conditional comments to serve a different stylesheet with the `filter` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CSS Opacity Properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736061/css-opacity-properties) , they are using " " around progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.alpha(opacity=100) which clears validation.

I assume the CSS still works correctly.