# CSS Opacity Properties?

Tags: css

Do I really need all these CSS Opacity Properties? I'm not using ALL of these at once, but showing them at different percentages.  But I usually have the group of 4 and I wanted to see if I can eliminate anything from my stylesheet.

And can someone show me an example of 100%, 25%, and 0%? I want to make sure I have them done correctly.

```
opacity: 1;
-moz-opacity: 1;
filter:alpha(opacity=1);
-ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";


opacity: 0.25;
-moz-opacity: 0.25;
filter:alpha(opacity=0.25);
-ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=25)";


opacity: 0;
-moz-opacity: 0;
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
-ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
}
```

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/a8uZX/   ?

Comment: @c69 thank you, but are all 4 of those needed?

Comment: If you don't need IE8 and below, then just use `opacity`. If you do need - then use short `filter: ..`. Sonic42 answered almost fine ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want CSS3 opacity across as many browsers as possible, you'll need all of these properties:

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";     /*Best for Internet Explorer 8 */
filter: alpha(opacity=50);    /*Internet Explorer 5, 6, 7, 8 */
-moz-opacity: 0.5;    /* Old Mozilla Browsers */
-webkit-opacity: 0.5;    /* Old Webkit browsers (Safari, Chrome, various others) */
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;    /* Really old Safari browsers and Konqueror */
opacity: 0.5;    /* Modern browsers */
```

However, you can cut most of those for modern usage:

```
filter: alpha(opacity=50);    /*Internet Explorer 5, 6, 7, 8 */
opacity: 0.5;    /* Modern browsers */
```

Note that while IE 8 support `filter`, it's not the recommended way to add opacity. However, it all works the same.

Comment: I am pretty sure IE9 doesn't need `filter:` anymore.

Comment: @sonic42 thank you! I use sublime text 2 and when I type opacity it adds opacity:, filter:, and -moz-opacity:  how old are the browsers that -moz-opacity supports?

Comment: IE9 supports `opacity` and is a modern browser.

Comment: @boltclock so it would be just opacity:?

Comment: **Firefox 0.9** was the most recent version of Firefox that did not understand unprefixed `opacity`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/opacity

Comment: @Bolt Thanks, I double-checked my facts and updated accordingly.

Comment: @c69 On top of that, Mozilla totally dropped support for `moz-opacity` back in FF 3.5.

Comment: wow 0.9 .. so I guess opacity and filter is what ill use thanks!

Comment: @c69: Best part is that it wasn't even called Firefox then, it was Firebird.

Comment: quick question, you said -ms-filter was best for IE8.. so should that be included?

Comment: @Joe Bobby: If you need IE8 support, yes, use that.

Comment: +1 for showing that you only really need to use `filter:` and `opacity:` these days.